# How to slim your war file by excluding jars already on the server using maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am developing a tomcat project, managed by maven in eclipse. I have to deploy it remotely and everytime I deploy it, maven copies all the jar files. I aim to use tomcat shared libs but I am not quite sure about the configuration ... here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  <groupId>com.springer</groupId>     <artifactId>GraphStatistics</artifactId>    <packaging>war</packaging>  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   <name>GraphStatistics Maven Webapp</name>   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  <dependencies>      <dependency>            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>           <artifactId>commons-jcs-core</artifactId>           <version>2.0-beta-1</version>       </dependency>       <dependency>            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>          <version>2.2.3</version>        </dependency>       <dependency>            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>             <version>7.0.47</version>       </dependency>       <dependency>            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>           <version>1.2</version>      </dependency>       <dependency>            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>           <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>            <version>1.1.1</version>        </dependency>   </dependencies>     <build>         <finalName>GraphStatistics</finalName>      <plugins>           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>blahblah</url>
                    <password>blah</password>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <path>/Yesyes</path>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Note that using shared libs may give classloader problems when reloading the war many times.  You can explicitly tell maven not to include a given dependency when building the war.  That might be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I get the permgen error quite often. Luckily its an isolated tomcat instance which I can simply restart. Okay, so, if I exlude the jars and put copies in the lib folder, this should be accessible to tomcat, right?

Comment: A permgen space errors is not related to excluding dependencies.

Comment: Try doing it by hand first. A war file is just a zip file with meta information.

Comment: You could check the program into svn or git and export it on the server. There run maven to get your dependencies downloaded. Or try Jenkins.

Comment: So if you manually remove the jar files in question from the war file (with winzip or careful use of jar) and have the shared libs in place, can you then deploy the war?